# Como realizar calculo de varios input com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom montei um sisteminha de calculo com jQuery bem sim, onde eu informo o custo de um produto. Ao informar o valor de venda o sistema realiza o calculo da margem, se eu informar a margem o sistema calcula o valor de venda.

Tudo isso com base no custo. O que estou tentando fazer é, qual eu alterar o custo todos os valores que que ser recalculados respeitando a margem.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Segue o que eu já fiz.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Faz o calculo da margem com base no valor
  $(".custo").on("keyup", function() {

    // aqui eu tenho que alterar todos os input valor
  });


  // Faz o calculo da margem com base no valor
  $(".valor").on("keyup", function() {

    // Valor
    var valor = $(this).val();
    valor = Formata_Moeda(valor);

    // Custo
    var custo = $('#custo').val();
    custo = Formata_Moeda(custo);

    // Calcula markup
    var calculo = (valor - custo) / custo * 100;

    // Formata valor para pt-br
    calculo = Formata_Dinheiro(calculo);

    // Verifica valor da margem
    if (calculo === "-Infinity") {
      calculo = 0;
    }

    // Atualiza input
    var inputMargem = $(this).attr("margem");
    $("#" + inputMargem).val(calculo).trigger('blur');
  });

  // Faz o calculo do valor com base na margem
  $(".margem").on("keyup", function() {

    // Margem
    var margem = $(this).val();
    margem = Formata_Moeda(margem);

    // Custo
    var custo = $('#custo').val();
    custo = Formata_Moeda(custo);

    // Calcula markup
    var calculo = (custo * margem / 100) + custo;

    // Formata valor para pt-br
    calculo = Formata_Dinheiro(calculo);

    // Atualiza input
    var inputValor = $(this).attr("valor");
    $("#" + inputValor).val(calculo).trigger('blur');
  });
});


function Formata_Moeda(valor) {
  // Remove todos os .
  valor = valor.replace(/\./g, "");

  // Troca todas as , por .
  valor = valor.replace(",", ".");

  // Converte para float
  valor = parseFloat(valor);
  valor = parseFloat(valor) || 0.0;

  return valor;
}

function Formata_Dinheiro(n) {
  return n.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\,)/g, "$1.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
custo:
<input type='text' class='custo' id='custo' name='custo' value='8'>

<br>
<br>
<br> Valor X Margem<br>
<input type='text' class='valor valores' id='valor1' name='valor1' margem='margem1' value='10'>
<input type='text' class='margem lucro' id='margem1' name='margem1' valor='valor1' value='25'>

<br>
<br>
<br> Valor X Margem<br>
<input type='text' class='valor valores' id='valor2' name='valor2' margem='margem2' value='20'>
<input type='text' class='margem lucro' id='margem2' name='margem2' valor='valor2' value='150'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite, inserir o seguinte código forçando as chamas aos eventos, não cheguei verificar se os valores calculados são o que está sendo esperado.

```
// Faz o calculo da margem com base no valor
      $(".custo").on("keyup", function() {
        // aqui eu tenho que alterar todos os input valor
        $(".valor").keyup();
        $(".margem").keyup();
      });
```

Segue código completo:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

   // Faz o calculo da margem com base no valor
   $(".custo").on("keyup", function() {
  // aqui eu tenho que alterar todos os input valor
  $(".valor").keyup();
  $(".margem").keyup();
   });


   // Faz o calculo da margem com base no valor
   $(".valor").on("keyup", function() {

  // Valor
  var valor = $(this).val();
  valor = Formata_Moeda(valor);

  // Custo
  var custo = $('#custo').val();
  custo = Formata_Moeda(custo);

  // Calcula markup
  var calculo = (valor - custo) / custo * 100;

  // Formata valor para pt-br
  calculo = Formata_Dinheiro(calculo);

  // Verifica valor da margem
  if (calculo === "-Infinity") {
    calculo = 0;
  }

  // Atualiza input
  var inputMargem = $(this).attr("margem");
  $("#" + inputMargem).val(calculo).trigger('blur');
   });

   // Faz o calculo do valor com base na margem
   $(".margem").on("keyup", function() {

  // Margem
  var margem = $(this).val();
  margem = Formata_Moeda(margem);

  // Custo
  var custo = $('#custo').val();
  custo = Formata_Moeda(custo);

  // Calcula markup
  var calculo = (custo * margem / 100) + custo;

  // Formata valor para pt-br
  calculo = Formata_Dinheiro(calculo);

  // Atualiza input
  var inputValor = $(this).attr("valor");
  $("#" + inputValor).val(calculo).trigger('blur');
   });
 });


 function Formata_Moeda(valor) {
   // Remove todos os .
   valor = valor.replace(/\./g, "");

   // Troca todas as , por .
   valor = valor.replace(",", ".");

   // Converte para float
   valor = parseFloat(valor);
   valor = parseFloat(valor) || 0.0;

   return valor;
 }

 function Formata_Dinheiro(n) {
   return n.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\,)/g, "$1.");
 }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
custo:
<input type='text' class='custo' id='custo' name='custo' value='8'>

<br>
<br>
<br> Valor X Margem<br>
<input type='text' class='valor valores' id='valor1' name='valor1' margem='margem1' value='10'>
<input type='text' class='margem lucro' id='margem1' name='margem1' valor='valor1' value='25'>

<br>
<br>
<br> Valor X Margem<br>
<input type='text' class='valor valores' id='valor2' name='valor2' margem='margem2' value='20'>
<input type='text' class='margem lucro' id='margem2' name='margem2' valor='valor2' value='150'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: obrigado, deu certinho.